# Filter a JSON array based on a property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON array like this:

```js
var records = [
  { Name: "Bob", EmployeeID: 1234, Status: "present" },
  { Name: "Jim", EmployeeID: 4432, Status: "present" },
  { Name: "Heather", EmployeeID: 4432, Status: "absent" },
]
```

And I want to filter the array list according to the status like(i.e if `Status === "present"`).

```
[
  { "Name": "Bob", "EmployeeID": 1234, "Status": "present" },
  { "Name": "Jim", "EmployeeID": 4432, "Status": "present" }
]
```

Comment: Hi Amit, welcome to StackOverflow! You originally stated that the array should be _sorted_ based on a condition. However, the expected output you're trying to get is completely different from _sorting_ the array (which should have the _same amount of items_) - instead, you're probably intending to _filter_ the array. So which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the `present` status records only.

> The `filter()` method creates a new `array` with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var records = [{
    "Name": "Bob",
    "EmployeeID": 1234,
    "Status": "present"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jim",
    "EmployeeID": 4432,
    "Status": "present"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Heather",
    "EmployeeID": 4432,
    "Status": "absent"
  }
];

let preStatus = records.filter(({Status}) => Status === 'present')
console.log(preStatus)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. It returns new array according to given condition.

```js
var records = [{"Name":"Bob", "EmployeeID":1234, "Status":"present"},
               {"Name":"Jim", "EmployeeID":4432, "Status":"present"},
               {"Name":"Heather", "EmployeeID":4432, "Status":"absent"}];
               
               
               
const output = records.filter(rec => {
   return rec.Status == 'present';
});


console.log(output);
```

Comment: Instead of plainly spoon-feeding code to the asker, please consider _explaining_ how your code helps to solve the asker's question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mentioning about filtering

```
  let recordSorted = []
    records.map(item => if(item.Status == "present"){
    recordSorted.push(item)
    })
```

2.you can simply do it by

```
records.map(item => item.Status === "present" ? recordSorted.push(item): continue )
```

3.you can use filter methods to filter itesm from array

```
var records = [
  { Name: "Bob", EmployeeID: 1234, Status: "present" },
  { Name: "Jim", EmployeeID: 4432, Status: "present" },
  { Name: "Heather", EmployeeID: 4432, Status: "absent" },
]

let recordSorted = records.filter(item=>{item.Status ==="present"})
```

learn more about [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

console.log(recordSorted)